# Recursive function in a CakePhHP Component not working

Tags: function, cakephp, recursion, components

I'm trying to use a recursive function wich list all folders/files in a directory.
The fact is this function doesn't callback, displaying "Call to undefined function list_directory_contents()".
I tried others recursive functions, same result.
Althought a friend doesn't seems to have the same problem.

Here is my function : `function list_directory_contents($dir){

```
     $dh = new DirectoryIterator($dir);    
     foreach ($dh as $item) {
         if (!$item->isDot()) {
            if ($item->isDir()) {
                list_directory_contents("$dir/$item");
            } else {
                echo $dir . "/" . $item->getFilename();
                echo "<br>";
            }
         }
      }
}`
```

Note that I'm using cakephp.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has nothing to do with recursion.  In cakePHP components, you're in a class.  Add $this-> before your method call.

[Calling functions in cakephp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15655322/calling-functions-in-cakephp)

Answer (score 0):

Use [Folder::findRecursive()](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/file-folder.html#Folder%3a%3afindRecursive).

Why are you echoing html from a component? That's plain wrong and violates the MVC pattern.

Comment: Well i used it as a helper too with the same result, so i tried with component but indeed, that wasn't the better choice.